# Access session scoped variable in spring interceptor

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

How can i access session scoped variable in spring interceptor?

Session scoped class:

```
@Component
@Scope("session")
public class User {
}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/restricted")
@Scope("request")
public class RestrictedController {
    @Autowired
    private User user;
}
```

Dispatcher servlet:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
        <mvc:interceptor>
            <mvc:mapping path="/restricted/*"/>
            <bean class="com.interceptors.RestrictedInterceptor" />
        </mvc:interceptor>
    </mvc:interceptors>
```

Interceptor class:

```
public class RestrictedInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    }
}
```

In prehandle i want to check if user is logged in (some other checks as well), how can i access session scoped user variable here? Autowiring user in Interceptor class throws exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to access your session-scoped user using the following code:

```
request.getSession().getAttribute("scopedTarget.user");
```

See related post [here](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/45681-spring-session-scope-related-what-is-scopedtarget) and `org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedProxyUtils` class.

Comment: i get null value